# How can I open Firefox with webbot?

Tags: python, firefox, webbot

I'm trying learn Web Bot but I realized that no matter what I changed, Web Bot's Browser() only opens Google Chrome. How can I make the default browser Firefox?

Comment: did you look at the docs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium for creating a web bot instead by using the below code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\geckodriver.exe")    
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```